# Comparing Age-Adjusted Mortality Rate between 2 groups

Tags: poisson-regression, method-comparison, mortality

Context: I am using national mortality database to compare the mortality of X disease by demographic factors. I divided the county based on social vulnerability scoring into 4 groups (1,2,3,4 based on which quartile). So I want to compare the mortality rate between group 4 vs group 1. I have calculated the age-adjusted mortality rate using US Standardized population.

I originally intended to find the ratio by directly dividing group 4 vs group 1 since both are using the same denominator ( US standardized population)
However, existing literature that has a similar methodology tends to use Poisson regression to compare both groups. I tried to replicate the calculation based on their data (with very minimal knowledge of statistics), I could get a similar mortality rate ratio, but the 95% confidence intervals were off. My 95% CI is always close to the ratio such as 1(1.001- 1.002) instead of 1(0.80-1.20) as in the research paper.

My question is can I compare them by dividing them directly ? Or is there any statistical method should I use?

PS: Statistics noob here.